# Who is the manufacturer of this 18650 Li ion battery?

Tags: batteries

My friend gave me 4 of these batteries to test their charge srorage capacity. I am just curious to know what is the manufacturer's name. I could not find any thing on Google about them.[image]

Comment: *"I want people to read something on this little thing I have.  Hey, I know, I'll make it small in a large picture, and orient it vertically even though the picture is horizontal!"*  No thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CJ is apparently the name and it stands for Cháng Jiāng (which is Chinese for Jangtze river). [Here's](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CJ-18650-2600mAh-3-6-3_60165557948.html) a link to some being sold on alibaba

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the manufacturer name, but CJ (Changjiang) gives a lot of results. I think these are referred to as "CJ-6".

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CJ-18650-2600mAh-3-6-3_60165557948.html

http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-PC-Genuine-CJ-18650-FST-2000mAh-Li-Ion-3-7V-Flat-Top-Battery-/252209320804

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the brand is FST

Comment: Link to product/brand? Or anything else to back up your claim, which goes against the other answers?